# android type_step_counter value stop counting up when app not in background

Tags: android, types, counter, sensors

I am using `type_step_counter` sensor in Service to get the step value from android phone. It gives me the value as I expected. When I close my app, shake the phone, and then open again the app, the step value from the sensor counts up (this is also as I expected). 
However, when I swipe the app from the background, shake the phone, and then open again the app, the value from the sensor doesn't increase.
I read the android documentation of type_step_counter that if we want the counter to keep working while the app stopped, we should not unregister the sensor if we want it to continuously working (see [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)). So, I don't unregister it, but it stopped counting.

Here is my code (sorry not to put all code for security reason):

```
public void onCreate(){
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mStepCounterSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    // edited (it was unregister)
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mStepCounterSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL); 

    return START_STICKY;
}

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
    float[] values = event.values;
    Log.d("onSensorChanged", "value: " + String.valueOf(values[0])); // <-- this value does not increase after app stopped
}
```

Does anyone has any clue on this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

when I swipe the app from the background - this means your app is completely closed.

START_STICKY will keep the service running even after application is closed.

On reopening application i think you are starting this service again and so OnStartCommand will be called.

```
 mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, mStepCounterSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Then the type_step_counter will be reinitialized.

You can have a look at this for your criteria

https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

Comment: really sorry I mistype something. It was registerListener in that line. Please see my edited code m(_ _)m. Thanks for the link, I will try which one is for my criteria.

Comment: i understand, Am just saying you are registering again so it will start from beginning again

Comment: Do you mean that is why the values[0] not increasing? (because I register it again)

Comment: I tried making flag that the value will be 1 if it is registered and saved it in shared preferenced. It was not registered again, but the step counter did not work. I also tried making the flag as a private variable only, it was registered again, and off course the step counter work again. Btw, if I installed another step counter app, my step counter works well even after I swiped my app. I'm afraid I have to add some permissions, but don't know what.